# How many pairs $(a,b)$ such that $\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}$ is in set $S=\{x \in \mathbb{R} : 0 \le x \le 1\}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Suppose $S=\{x \in \mathbb{R} : 0 \le x \le 1\}$. Then how many pairs $(a,b)$ such that $S$ has exactly $2018$ elements that can be written as $\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}$, where $x,y$ are integers.

Here's what I have attempted, not much but here:

We know the form $\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}$ is in $S$, so it can be concluded: $$0 \le \frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b} \le 1 $$

Which can be written again as: $$0 \le xb+ ya \le ab$$

I'm not sure where to go from here, I know that $ab$ and $xb+ya$ are integers but I can't go anywhere from there...

Comment: We have from subtraction $0 \leq ab - xb-yb  $ if we add $ xy $ to both sides we will receive diophantic inequality

Comment: I see that will give me $(x-a)(x-b) \ge xy$, upon dividing by $x$ and $y$ I arrived at $(1-\frac{a}{x})(1-\frac{b}{y}) \ge 1$.

Comment: What is the source of the question?

Comment: @JAB note that $x,y$ are _integers_ (not necessarily positive). Does $bx+ya$ ring a bell? (Bezout)

Comment: Problem from the 2018 Indonesian MO City level. 

Yes I know about Bezout's Identity, I will try and explore using that path, thanks!

Comment: Now that I know it is not from an ongoing contest, here's a better hint: for $ab\ge bx+ay \ge 0$, $bx+ay$ can take the values $0, g, 2g, \ldots ab$ where $g = \gcd(a,b)$. You need these as 2018.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $0 \le \frac{bx+ay}{ab} \le 1$. By [Bezout's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity), any number of the form $bx+ay, x,y \in \Bbb Z$ is a multiple of $g = \gcd(a,b)$. Moreover, for any multiple of $g$, finding the infinite family of solutions $(x,y)$ is possible.

So, $bx+ay$ takes the values $0,g,2g \ldots ab$ in the desired interval. These are a total of $ab/g + 1 = \mathrm{lcm}(a,b)+1$ numbers. We are given $\mathrm{lcm}(a,b) + 1 = 2018 \iff \mathrm{lcm}(a,b) = 2017$.

Note that $2017$ is prime. Hence, $$\boxed{(a,b) \in \{(1,2017), (2017,1), (2017,2017)\}}$$giving 3 pairs.